# My website look is different between Google chrome and fire fox?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4, responsive

My website is pixel perfect in firefox but it does not show its real look in google chrome, but I use bootstrap-4 and responsive breakpoints for my website . But why they are not working properly?

Comment: Both browsers will always show a small difference. For instance, small texts (like `12px`) just display differently in Chrome because the anti-aliasing is different. If you have other issues, please be specific of the thing that is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is asked over and over again (with different combinations of browsers and rendering engines). But there's not really an answer. Instead, here are a few things to keep in mind to make your work look more similar across MOST popular browsers and devices.

**One**

**There's no such thing as complete pixel perfection.** Period. Even if you manage to get hit a point where a screenshot laid over the top of the source material (Photoshop, Sketch, etc) is exactly perfect, you could go to a different computer (same browser and source material) and not have it line up. But even that's unlikely as something like a Photoshop file by definition can't be responsive.

---

**Two**

**You CAN level the playing field to make most browsers treat your code similarly.** To do this, you need to understand that each browser has different defaults and then REMOVE those defaults so that your CSS represents the final solution. There are two typical ways to do this:

1. CSS Resets - these remove ALL styling and force you to build up everything.
2. [CSS Normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) - which attempts to make the base styling THE SAME across all browsers. (I use a normalize in EVERY project I do)

---

**Three**

Learn about the CSS `box-model`. The relates to how browsers deal with the "boxes" of [margin/padding/content](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) that make up a rendered HTML page. The box model a browser is using, impacts sizes and spacing. A Normalize will typically fix this, but many browsers use different box models by default.

It's also worth paying attention to screen pixel densities (this impacts anything with fixed sizes) and converting to percentage-based sizing (`rem`, `vh/vw`, `%`) so that all devices start to render things as close to what you wanted as possible.

---

**Four**

Get to know each browser's capabilities and plan `fallbacks` or `shims` to restore/add functionality in those cases. First, check what you're trying to use with [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/) This will tell you if you need to use a fallback, detect missing features or just accept the fact that it won't work exactly like you want it to everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is very common to see as you are designing a website. If you are fine with the look you can keep it how it is or what some developers will do is check the browser using jquery or check on the server-side. You can do a simple call and maybe set class on your body and style accordingly. I wish you luck! Here is a link to jQuery browser detection: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/

Comment: Please don't do browser detection in 2019! This has been [proven problematic](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/not_browser_detect.html) over and over again. Instead, feature detection with either @supports or Modernizr is future proof and now considered best practice.

Comment: @BryceHowitson That is good to know. But I thought that was to support outdated browsers that do not recognize the style. Some browsers render styling differently but supports won't makeup accordingly right?

Comment: You're correct that its mostly used for availability of a feature. But the issue in this case is that even the same `user-agent` will render differently across OS or devices. So trying to catch all of those differenes is almost impossible. The bigger deal though is that `user-agent` is often miss-reported or spoofed. A great example of this is IE in standards mode vs normal. Feature detection tells you what the browser is "acting like" not what it says it is.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, some attributes aren't supported or rendered the same from chrome to firefox. Most noticeable attributes are position. I advice you to look into [modernizr plugin](https://modernizr.com/), it's very good to handle different browsers CSS